# Is there a way to create a textbox on one page, based on the actions in another page?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I give the option for a user to delete a special offer on the `DeleteSpecialOffer` page .  If they click "Submit", it will return them to the `SpecialOffers` page.  I want to be able to display a message on the `SpecialOffers` page that confirms that the SO was successfully deleted.

Is there a way to create this textbox from the `DeleteSpecialOffer` page or possibly just make a hidden textbox visible?

Comment: Its a web app, so you can pass parameters signaling the state of something being deleted, created, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure, here's one option:

Have the textbox hidden (Visible="False") on the `SpecialOffers` page and when you redirect the user from the DeleteSpecialOffer page, pass a parameter in the URL as so:

```
Response.Redirect("SpecialOffers.aspx?Success=Y");
```

In `SpecialOffers` check whether this parameter is "Y" and make the textbox visible programmatically. Something like:

```
if(Request.QueryString["Success"]=="Y"))
{
   txtBox.Visible=true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just pass a parameter to your page and request that parameter when you need it.

`http://mysite/SpecialOffers?ID=42001&Deleted=1`

The parameter can be read back in and displayed.
In this case `ID` represents the IDentifier of your "special offer" and Deleted is simply a boolean parameter on whether it was deleted or not.  To read it back in

`bool b = (bool)Request.QueryString(["Deleted"]);`

You can read the `Deleted` parameter from your redirected page and check if it was really deleted or not.  You can also verify the deletion before showing a message since you have both the ID and the state (Whether it was deleted or not).

The end result is

```
bool b = (bool)Request.QueryString(["Deleted"]);`

//you can verify this given the ID and boolean value if you wanted
if (b) {
//was deleted
}
else {
//not deleted
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you dont want to use a querystring based system you could use a standard `asp:LinkButton` or `asp:Button`. You could then change the `PostBackUrl` property to your `SpecialOffers` page and then in the `Page_Load` event of the `SpecialOffers` go dig up the form state from the previous `DeleteSpecialOffer` page, like this:

```
Page.Form["Your control on the DeleteSpecialOffer page"]
```